# How do i reference the IWebDriver variable in another method?

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use webdriver in C# to automate a few tasks. I created a method called logInAutomation such as this:

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

and then when the button is clicked, I reference that method in the event handler like this:

```
private void testButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
logInAutomation();
}
```

The problem is, I need to reference the IWebDriver again but the only way I know how to code it is by retyping:

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

which causes another chrome window to be opened. How do I reference the IWebDriver in the event handler method without opening a new window? Sorry if my terminology is off, I'm new to coding so please let me know if you need clarification.

Here is the entire Code:

```
namespace Automation_Suite
{
    public partial class redSuite : Form
    {

        public redSuite()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        static public void logInAutomation()
        {
            //Opens Chrome Window and navigates to Autoloop Log in
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Url = "DESTINATION URL";

            //Finds Username field and enters username
            IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Name("USERNAME LOG IN"));
            element.SendKeys("USERNAME");

            //Finds Password field and enters password
            element = driver.FindElement(By.Name("PASSWORD AUTOMATION"));
            element.SendKeys("PASSWORD");

            //Clicks Submit
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("SUBMIT BUTTON")).Click();
        }

        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void hostedGalleryBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            logInAutomation();

            IWebElement element = element = driver.FindElement(By.Name("COMPANY ID"));
            element.SendKeys("ID NUMBER");
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Can you not work with the existing `driver` you've already defined?  Just do `driver.` (note the `.`) and reference the method for whatever you're trying to accomplish.  When you say you're wanting to "*reference the IWebDriver again*", what exactly are you wanting to do at any additional event handler calls?

Comment: Where are you defining driver? Is it in the class or inside a method? If you declare it in the class you'll be able to use it within methods.

Comment: I just updated my original post so you can see the code, just in case I'm not explaining it well enough.

I am trying to figure out how I can use the IWebDriver that is already stated in the logInAutomation method inside the hostedGalleryBtn_Click method without opening a new web browser :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define "driver" as a [class field member](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173113.aspx), not inside a method, but inside the class scope instead.

```
namespace Automation_Suite
{
    public partial class redSuite : Form
    {
        private IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); //define driver here so you can use it in methods.

        public redSuite()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void logInAutomation()
        {

            driver.Url = "DESTINATION URL";

            //Finds Username field and enters username
            IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Name("USERNAME LOG IN"));
            element.SendKeys("USERNAME");

            //Finds Password field and enters password
            element = driver.FindElement(By.Name("PASSWORD AUTOMATION"));
            element.SendKeys("PASSWORD");

            //Clicks Submit
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("SUBMIT BUTTON")).Click();
        }

        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void hostedGalleryBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            logInAutomation();

            IWebElement element = element = driver.FindElement(By.Name("COMPANY ID"));
            element.SendKeys("ID NUMBER");
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: ah ha! I tried that before and was having the same problem.

Looks like I was just missing the "static private" tags for the method. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Yup, I removed the static for my answer since your class isnt static. also they're private by default, I just like to add that for clarity. If this answers your question don't forget to mark it as so ;)